# Выборка гостиниц по ценам номеров

Tags: mysql, sql

Здравствуйте!
Есть две таблицы
1. Таблица объектов objects (гостиницы, отели, квартиры)
поля:

```
idobj, parentid, name и т.п.
1   0         Отель Изумрудный
2   1         Номер Люкс 
3   1         Номер Стандарт
4   0         Квартира
5   0         Гостевой дом Морской
```

2. Таблица цен prices (значения поля type: 1 - цена за помещение, 2 - за человека)

```
idprice, objid, cost, date1,      date2,      type 
1        2      1000  2018-01-01  2018-03-31  2
2        2      1500  2018-04-01  2018-04-15  2
3        3      500   2018-01-01  2018-03-31  2
4        4      1000  2018-02-10  2018-05-15  1
5        4      1500  2018-05-16  2018-08-31  1
6        5      1000  2018-05-15  2018-09-30  1
```

Пользователь указывает дату заезда и выезда, а также минимальную и максимальную цену и начинает поиск подходящих объектов.
Не было бы проблем если бы в базе были только квартиры, но у гостиниц номерная система и цены связаны с номерами гостиниц. Подскажите, пожалуйста, можно ли одним запросом найти все подходящие объекты?

Пока вижу решение только в 2 запроса.

Comment: В приведенном примере данных не замечено никакой разницы между квартирами и гостиницами, а по сему не ясно, для чего могли бы понадобится 2 запроса

Comment: В ценах квартиры указан идентификатор квартиры. У цен гостиниц указан идентификатор номера. Номер привязан к гостинице через parentid. Т.е. через left join не получится.

Comment: Тоже не пойму, для чего тут два запроса. Одним запросом достаем объекты с ценой из указанного диапазона в нужные даты. Готово.

Comment: Я могу достать одним запросом подходящие номера и квартиры. А как достать одним запросом квартиры и гостиницы (у которых номера подходят по параметрам цен).